# Module 'AdServices' not found (react-native)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I have a react-native project and react-native-branch installed.
Pods successfully installed with `npm install` and `pod install` command.

[image]

But when I running this project with Xcode on iOS simulator, I got this error:

```
Module 'AdServices' not found
```

in this file:

```
Pods > Pods > Branch > BNCSystemObserver.m
```

[image]

Note: I delete the Pods folder and Podfile.lock file and try to build again, but got the same error in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just struggled with this myself for about a day, where the build worked fine on my machine but was failing on CI. Make sure you're using an up-to-date version of Xcode; the `AdServices` framework was only added in Xcode 12.3. My local system was using the latest, 12.5, but CI was using Xcode 12.0. Upgrading the CI's version of Xcode fixed this issue and allowed me to build.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the same error over here, I think it's a compatibility issue on ios.

Comment: OK, So what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Using XCode 12.3 solved the problem for me, hope it will help you !